# ASP.NET charting control - first charts show blank at first load of page

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a page which generates four graphs using the ASP.NET 4.0 charting control and displays them. The charts are created in the code-behind on Page Load and added into a table on the page.

My problem is that when the page loads, the first 1 or more graphs (usually just one, but sometimes 2 or 3) are blank (the user gets an empty outlined box of the size of the graph with a red X in the upper left corner).

Refreshing the page causes all graphs to properly render.

Any ideas on how to get the graphs to populate on the first pass?

Here is the code that generates a chart and adds it to the page (the routine containing this code is called 4 times).  Note that the 'points' object contains a collection of Name-Value pairs, where the Name is the Label to be displayed on the X-Axis, and the Value is the numeric Y-Axis value:

```
Chart graph = new Chart();
graph.Width = 800;
graph.Height = 400;
Series series = new Series();
series.Name = "Series1";
series.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Bright;
series.IsXValueIndexed = true;
for (int j = 0; j < points.Count; j++)
{
    DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(j+1.0, points.GetItem(j).Value);
    dataPoint.AxisLabel = points.GetItem(j).Name.Trim();                    
    series.Points.Add(dataPoint);
}
graph.Series.Add(series);
ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
chartArea.Name = "ChartArea1";
chartArea.AxisX.Interval = 1;
chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "###,###,###,###";
graph.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
graph.Titles.Add(caption);

TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell td = new TableCell();
td.Width = new Unit(100.0, UnitType.Percentage);
tblGraph.Rows.Add(tr);
tr.Cells.Add(td);
td.Controls.Add(graph);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. The Chart images ARE written to the file system, but this happens about 20ms after the page is rendered. If you put your code to sleep for, say, 20 milliseconds after rendering the Chart control, the issue won't happen - There will be time for the images to be written to the disk.

Comment: Did you find that documented anywhere?

Comment: I tried this with no luck, even with delays of up to 2500 ms.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the process to do that (the delay in rendering the page)?  I have the same issue off and on.  In development, the graph (only one here) doesn't display 9 out of 10 times.  In production, the graph DOES display about 7 out of 10 times.  It's that 3 out of 10 that I want to fix.